# Alamofire 5: Upload Failed: Response could not be decoded because of error: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

As the title says, Alamofire 5 is telling me that the data is missing, yet it is not.

This is the data I have in my console along with the error

```
dic=== {"lat": "26.9342246", "message": "Test", "lng": "-80.0942087", "receiver_id": "269", "messageType": "text", "chatType": "fix", "product_variant_id": "", "receiverType": "customer", "customer_id": "213", "itemType": "sell", "product_id": "25", "service_id": "", "fileName": ""}
Result: failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "message", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"message\", intValue: nil) (\"message\").", underlyingError: nil)))))
Upload Failed: Response could not be decoded because of error:
The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.
```

These are my Decodable's

```
struct MessageModel : Decodable {
                let data : [MessageModelData]?
                let message : String
                
                enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                        case message, data
                    }
            }

            struct  MessageModelData : Decodable {
                let fileType : String
                let groupID, id : Int
                let intetestCustomerID, itemType, message, messageType : String
                let productID, productOwnerID, profileImg, profileName :String
                let receiveID, receiverType, sendAt : String
                
                enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                        case groupID = "groupId"
                        case intetestCustomerID = "intetest_customer_id"
                        case productID = "product_id"
                        case productOwnerID  = "product_owner_id"
                        case receiveID = "receiveId"
                        case fileType, id, itemType, message, messageType, profileImg, profileName, receiverType, sendAt
                    
                    }
                
            }
```

Am I missing something? I changed `message` to an optional and then it said unexpectedly found nil, I'm very confused as clearly the message variable is in the response.

Here's where it errors

```
func sendChatProductImage(header: String, parameter: String, coverdata: UIImage, mimetype : String ,vc: UIViewController, showHud: Bool,completion : @escaping(_ success : Bool, _ message : String, _ response : NSDictionary) -> Void) {
        webService_obj.chatProductImageSend(header: header, withParameter: parameter, coverdata: coverdata, mimetypeExtention: mimetype, inVC: vc, showHud: showHud) { (response, success) in
            if success{
                let message = response["message"]
                completion(success, message as! String, response )
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I figured out why, but I don't know how to resolve it.

I have my upload here with Alamofire 5, and I have the decodable, but it is not properly decoding it to the right data, or I'm using the response wrong

```
AF.upload(
                multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    var dic = parameter.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "{")
                    dic = dic.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "}")
                    print("dic===",dic)
                    multipartFormData.append("\(dic)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "data")
                    if coverimageData != nil {
                        multipartFormData.append(coverimageData!, withName: "file", fileName: "chatImage.jpg", mimeType: "*/*")
                    }else{
                        multipartFormData.append("".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "file")
                    }
                    
            },
                with: uploadUrl).responseDecodable(of: MessageModel.self) { response in
                    print("Result: \(response)")
                    
                    if hud {
                        Loader.init().hide(delegate: vc)
                    }
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let result):
                        let dataResponse = response.value(forKey: "data" as? NSDictionary)
                        completion(dataResponse, true)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        let err = error.localizedDescription
                        print("Upload Failed: \(err)")
                        completion([:], false)
                        self.presentAlertWithTitle(title: kAPPName, message: err, vc: vc)
                        break
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Your line that prints `dic===` is printing the document you are *sending*, but it seems that your failure is decoding the response into an instance of `MessageModel`.  What response data are you actually getting?  It seems that it doesn't have a `message` property

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why it's not decoding the info properly. I've printed the `response.value` and it seems it's not decoding it properly, as `message` and `data` are nil. Is there a better way to debug it rather then just printing?

Comment: @Paulw11 after printing the response using a new decodable it is this
`Result: success(YACHT_NOW.Config.(unknown context at $10795e5ec).(unknown context at $10795e924).MessageBoardModelNew(status_code: nil, message: nil, data: nil))
reponseData: Optional(YACHT_NOW.Config.(unknown context at $10795e5ec).(unknown context at $10795e924).MessageBoardModelNew(status_code: nil, message: nil, data: nil))
`

Comment: That's the result of trying to decode whatever response your server came back with as an instance of `MessageModel` - But since all of the properties are `nil` I don't think that is what your server is responding with. Rather than trying to decode the response, just get the raw data from the server, convert it to a string and print it.  That will show you what you need to decode.

Comment: @Paulw11 How do I figure out what the raw data is? TL;DR - I took over the app's development from a team of third world developers and they use http://mydevfactory.com to send/receive the requests, I have left it to fix some crashes, but I can't find the request in their documentation which is on Postman. I'm basing these decodings on what their `Codable`'s are. It's been a horrid experience fixing their 5 year out of date code.

Comment: Also just to clarify the data is definitely getting sent. When I rebuild the app and it get's the data from the server it's showing properly.
This is an example of the data
`{"id":"574","chatId":"152","senderId":"213","senderType":"customer","messageType":"text","message":"Hey sup","file":"","fileName":"","fileType":"","lat":"26.9342246","lng":"-80.0942087","price":"","quote_id":"","created":"2023-03-05 10:19:43","itemType":"sell","profileImg":"uploads\/customer\/image\/7c534cc138b11562a73cc92247227b48.jpg","is_order":"no"}`

Comment: could you add `print("----> \(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8))")` before
 `print("Result: \(response)")` and show us what it prints.

Comment: Unrelated, since the error is in the decoding of the response (ie, upload was fine, but reading the error isn't done correctly) but seeing how you construct `dict`, could you share how you fill the `parameter: String` when calling the method? I suspect a `"\(value)"`

Comment: Sorry it took me two days to get back to you two! I was uploading my own version of the API and now I have better control over it. Here's what that `print("----> \(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8))")` returns @workingdogsupportUkraine what is essentially "Customer not found", though it returns it as `{\"response\":{\"status_code\":202,\"message\":\"Customer not found.\"}}`

Trying to find a good way to debug WHY it says that, as I've tested it with my own POST request and it worked, so the issue is the format of the data

Comment: OKAY AFTER DEBUGGING FINALLY I figured out that Alamofire is sending this response `{"file":"","0":"{\"product_variant_id\": \"\", \"receiver_id\": \"269\", \"fileName\": \"\", \"messageType\": \"text\", \"chatType\": \"fix\", \"service_id\": \"\", \"product_id\": \"25\", \"customer_id\": \"524\", \"lng\": \"-80.0942087\", \"message\": \"Test\", \"receiverType\": \"customer\", \"itemType\": \"sell\", \"lat\": \"26.9342246\"}"}` so now I need to figure out how it's supposed to be sent lol

Comment: Okay, so decoded that successfully, and now I get success, but Alamofire 5 still does not decode the object properly. `Optional("{\"response\":{\"status_code\":200,\"message\":\"Message sent successfully.\",\"data\":\"154\"}}")` becomes `MessageDataType(status_code: nil, message: nil, data: nil))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see your `MessageModel` struct does not **match** the
json data you get from the server in response to your`upload`.
In particular there is no `response` property. Similarly for `MessageDataType`.

Try the following models, to decode the response you get from the server after you have sent your data to it:

```
struct PostResponse: Codable {
    let response: MessageDataType    <-- here
}

struct MessageDataType: Codable {
    let status_code: Int
    let message, data: String
}
```

and decode the response like this:

```
 //...
    with: uploadUrl).responseDecodable(of: PostResponse.self) { <-- here
 //....
```

You will have to read the server docs to determine which of the properties
should be optional, in that case add `?` to it.

EDIT-1

To decode the response you are now showing, instead of the one you showed us before,

`Optional("{\"response\":{\"status_code\":200,\"message\":\"Message sent successfully.\",\"data\":\"154\"}}")`

use the following models:

```
struct PostResponse: Codable {
    let response: StatusResponse
}

struct StatusResponse: Codable {
    let status_code: Int
    let message: String
    let data: DataClass
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let chatId, senderId, receiveId, senderType: String
    let message, lat, lng, file: String
    let fileName, fileType, messageType: String
}
```

Comment: Failed again.
`----> Optional("{\"response\":{\"status_code\":200,\"message\":\"Message sent successfully.\",\"data\":{\"chatId\":\"152\",\"senderId\":\"213\",\"receiveId\":\"269\",\"senderType\":\"customer\",\"message\":\"Oh yeah\",\"lat\":\"26.9342246\",\"lng\":\"-80.0942087\",\"file\":\"\",\"fileName\":\"\",\"fileType\":\"\",\"messageType\":\"text\"}}}")`

Comment: `Result: failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "response", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)))))`

Comment: updated my answer to cater for the new response that you show in your comment.